# Unexpected token ILLEGAL with @inject

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia, gulp-jshint

I'm using gulp-jshint and receiving this message with a javascript file.  The file is a simple service class in my Aurelia app.  Here is the code:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {MyService} from './app/service/MyService';

/* jshint ignore:start */
@inject(MyService)
/* jshint ignore:end */
export class App {

    constructor(MyService) {
        this.message = MyService.message;
    }

}
```

Here is my gulp task (gulp-jshint is getting loaded using gulp-load-plugins):

```
gulp.task('vet', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.alljs)
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.print()))
        .pipe($.jscs())
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jscsStylish.combineWithHintResults())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {verbose: true}))
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
```

I have `"esversion": 6` in my .jshintrc

This is the result of running `gulp vet` (in both Powershell and cmd)

```
PS C:\_files\programming\MyProj> gulp vet
[11:42:21] Using gulpfile C:\_files\programming\MyProj\gulpfile.js
[11:42:21] Starting 'vet'...

web\app.js
  line 5  col 1  Unexpected token ILLEGAL  (W parseError)

  ‼  1 warning

[11:42:23] 'vet' errored after 1.79 s
[11:42:23] Error in plugin 'gulp-jshint'
Message:
    JSHint failed for: web\app.js
PS C:\_files\programming\MyProj>
```

The Aurelia app works just fine.  JSHint is ignoring the `@inject` within VSCode also, no problem there.  For some reason, though, gulp-jshint won't let it go.  I've deleted and retyped the line after searching and finding a lot of issues with non-printable characters.  I've tried switching the jshint ignore to `// jshint ignore:line` syntax.  Still nothing.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

JSHint does not support **decorators** ("@whatever") yet, so `esversion: 6` will not affect this issue.

> The policy of JSHint is to support features that are Stage 2 of 
>   standardization process, which is not the case yet for decorators.

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2310

Not sure why your "ignore" directive is failing, though. Maybe try the single-line ignore directive?
`@inject(MyService)// jshint ignore:line`

Edit: Ignoring a single line doesn't work for me either. Sorry, this answer probably won't be helpful. :-(